# Is the OAuth Client is a must to connect on the Oauth server?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I've been working for several days dealing with the OAuth2.0 server. My problem was, do i have to create an oauth client to every platform(android, ios) that connects to my oauth2.0 server ? because right now, since that I am on testing, I used postman to pass the client_id and client_secret. Anyway, I used client_credentials grant type. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, OAuth2.0 spec specify you must pass some form client credentials to tell the authentication server that you are legit.

check out https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3

so purpose is,

- Only valid clients can able to communicate with authentication server
- you can customize access based on client types confidential or public, and validate if access token is issued to one of valid clients.
- when your client credentials is exposed, authentication server can easily disable that specify oauth client, without blocking other applications of yours

Comment: So I'll be using an OAuth2.0 client library to every platform to connect to my OAuth2.0 server. Thank you so much, I understand it very well now.

Comment: Can I just used curl to connect to my oauth2.0 server? will it be secured just like using oauth2.0 client? Thanks!

Comment: Even for curl I believe you need to send oauth client Info right for server to identify it.

Comment: I am referring to the oauth2 client library. I am asking if this client library is a must to connect to my oauth2 server. I am not referring to the client info. At oauth2.net/2/ they gave oauth server and client libraries so I am wondering if i have to use Curl in php rather than using the oauth2 client library.

Comment: oh okay, its not necessary, its just network call, any networking tool or built in library can be used to make network request and get the response

Comment: I get it. Have you been using oauth2.0, right? what do you prefer to call the the oauth2.0 server, built in library or curl? Because my concern now is the security of the two. Or if you have your other way to call the oauth2.0 server  that is secured, suggestions is okay.  Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't think you should worry about security in using the library , it's mostly open source , you can check the code by yourself. However if you really concerned about it you should built your own , in my case I am the one who built he auth server in my company , so I built an SDK as an convenience